# Each object random size

Tags: jquery, function, random

This snippet creates snow falling effect, I have been playing around with it trying to get different size flakes but so far have only been able to make them change size on page refresh, what I really want is for each flake to be a different size, (or at least have 2 or 3 different sizes) any help please?

```
var snowCount = 0,
fs = Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 20) + 20);
function snowFlakes(){
 var randomTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500) * 2);
 setTimeout(function(){
 snowCount = snowCount +2;
  jquerysnow();
  snowFlakes();
 },randomTime);
}
function jquerysnow() {
 var snow = $('<div class="snow" style="font-size:'+fs+'px;"></div>'),
       dH = $(document).height() + 'px',
       sf = $('#snowflakes');
 sf.prepend(snow);
   snowX = Math.floor(Math.random() * sf.width());
 snowSpd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500) * 20);
 snow.css({'left':snowX+'px'});
 snow.html('&#x2744;');
 snow.animate({top : dH, opacity : '1',}, 9000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
}
snowFlakes();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnbks/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the `fs` variable only once. If you create it within the `jquerysnow` function, you should be set. I forked your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnbks/1/.

Comment: Thank you very much, will mark as answer when I can (6 mins) :)